# Mayavi - Saving multiple plot3d objects in single vtk file

Tags: python, mayavi

This function plots multiple contours and displays them in a Mayavi window.  After this happens I am trying to save the output to a VTK file.  Currently I am only able to save one contour to a file.  I know that the saving is outside of the array and of course only the final object will be saved.  Does anyone know how to access all the objects and save them in one go?

```
def plotContour(self, x, y, z):

    for i in range(len(x)):
        # Add each plot3d object to mayavi
        plot3dOutput = mlab.plot3d(x[i], y[i], z[i], tube_radius=1.5)

    # Display the output in Mayavi window
    mlab.show()

    # Write the object to a .vtk file
    plot3dOutput.module_manager.source.save_output('output.vtk')
```